# Why does Liquibase Maven update goal fail with errors while command line works?

Tags: maven-plugin, liquibase

I have been trying to get Liquibase's maven plugin to work with a simple SQL Changeset.

It's a slightly modified version of the example at: http://www.liquibase.org/manual/formatted_sql_changelogs

```
-- liquibase formatted sql

-- changeset nvoxland:1

CREATE TABLE test1 (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE test2 (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    name2 varchar(255)
);
```

The problem is, it fails with an error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE test2
```

If I remove the second create statement, it will succeed.

This happens, when trying to run it with Maven, using the liquibase-plugin. If I run the same changelog file using the command line tool, it will execute without errors.

My liquibase-plugin is of version 1.9.5.0 and liquibase-core is 2.0.5.

The database is MySql 5.5.27 and JDBC Driver is 5.1.24 - I used the same driver with Maven and the command line tool.

Comment: It looks like your maven plugin doesn't split the sql on `;`. Can you try again with org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:2.0.5?

Comment: that fixed it! Please post an answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `liquibase-plugin` is really old (from 2009) and doesn't split the SQL on `;`. You should use `org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:2.0.5` instead, which is the current version.